# Kivy package when using build.py

Tags: android, package, apk, kivy

When trying to package my app into an APK  I keep getting an error that package is required. on the kivy instructions it doesn't really explain what this is other than  --package . Can anyone explain what this is because I've no idea. 
Source: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html?highlight=package

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the parameter `--package`?  It just refers to the package of your own application. They give you an example on the [link](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html?highlight=package) you are providing.

```
./build.py --dir ~/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer \
--package org.demo.touchtracer \
--name "Kivy Touchtracer" --version 1.1.0 debug installd
```

On that example, `org.demo.touchtracer` actually refers to one of the Kivy examples that you can find [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/touchtracer).

Answer (score 1):

This is the identifier you want to give to your application, i was confused by this at first too, but you can chose whatever you want, just try to have something that clearly identify you or your company as the author, and identify the project, to avoid collision with other projects (i guess google would reject an apk using an already existing package name by a different author, but i never tried), but you get to decide what you put there, it's just a name.